# フォームの入力内容が一致しないときにメッセージを表示させたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

メールフォームの作成において二つのメールアドレスが一致しないときにエラーメッセージを表示させたいのですがJavaScriptが全く機能していません。どこのコードをまちがえているのか解決法とともに教えていただきたいです。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mail form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://cim.saddleback.edu/~jstudent0/formData.php">
    Email 1<input type="text" id="email1" name="email1"
                  pattern="\w+@\w{1,63}\.[a-z]{3}"
                  required="required"
                  title="Enter your email"/> <br>
    Email 2<input type="text" id="email2" name="email2"
                  pattern="\w+@\w{1,63}\.[a-z]{3}"
                  required="required"
                  title="Enter your email again"/> <br>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
      function checkMatch( ) {
  if( $("#email1").val() != "" &&
      $("#email1").val() == $("#email2").val() )
        return true;

  var msg = "Email2s not matching!"
   + $("#email2").val();

  console.log( msg );
  $("#prompt").text( msg );
  $("#prompt").css(
    { "color":"lime", "background-color":"black",
      "font-weight":"bolder" } );
  return false;
}
$(document).ready( function() {


  $("#email1").focus( function() {
    $("#prompt").text( "Enter First Email" );
  });

  $("#email1").blur( function() {
    $("#prompt").text( "Email2 must match email1");
  });

  $("#email2").keydown( function() {
    checkMatch();
    return true;
    //continue processing
  });

  $("form").submit( checkMatch );

});
 </script>
 <input type="submit" /><input type="reset" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryを読み込むscriptタグは、 `<head>` 内に書く必要があります。

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

そして、 `function checkMatch( ) {` 以下は `<body>` 内に `<script>` で囲って記載する必要があります。

```
<body>
  <script>
    console.log("hoge");
  </script>
</body>
```

試してみてください。

Comment: 無事動きました。ありがとうございます！